# Missing route parameter in nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am trying to include a resource into my routes file that shows the addresses of a customer via the url `customers/1/addresses`.

This is constructed with the following routes code:

```
resources :customers do
   resources :addresses
end
```

However when I access the URL `customers/1/addresses` I'm thrown an exception

> Couldn't find Customer with 'id'=

This error is caused by the following:

```
def set_customer
   @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
end
```

Now, this is because before the `:show` action is run on the customers controller it's calling the `set_customer` action.

How to only run the `set_customer` on the `/customer/:customer_id:` route?

And exclude `set_customer` on the `/customer/:customer_id:/addresses/` route?

---

**EDIT** As Requested the Full Stack Trace

```
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/core.rb:155:in `find'
app/controllers/customers_controller.rb:67:in `set_customer'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432:in `block in make_lambda'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:145:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:145:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `each'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.1.3) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
/Users/xavier/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/xavier/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/xavier/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

---

**EDIT** customers_controller.rb

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_customer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /customers
  # GET /customers.json
  def index
    @customers = Customer.all
  end

  # GET /customers/1
  # GET /customers/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /customers/new
  def new
    @customer = Customer.new
  end

  # GET /customers/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /customers
  # POST /customers.json
  def create
    @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @customer.save
        format.html { redirect_to @customer, notice: 'Customer was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @customer }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /customers/1
  # PATCH/PUT /customers/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @customer.update(customer_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @customer, notice: 'Customer was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @customer }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /customers/1
  # DELETE /customers/1.json
  def destroy
    @customer.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to customers_url, notice: 'Customer was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_customer
      @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def customer_params
      params.require(:customer).permit(:first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :cyrillic_first_name, :cyrillic_middle_name, :cyrillic_last_name, :email_address, :hashed_password, allergen_ids: [])
    end
end
```

---

**Edit** Addresses Controller

```
class AddressesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_address, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /addresses
  # GET /addresses.json
  def index
    @addresses = Address.all
  end

  # GET /addresses/1
  # GET /addresses/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /addresses/new
  def new
    @address = Address.new
  end

  # GET /addresses/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /addresses
  # POST /addresses.json
  def create
    @address = Address.new(address_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @address.save
        format.html { redirect_to @address, notice: 'Address was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @address }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @address.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /addresses/1
  # PATCH/PUT /addresses/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @address.update(address_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @address, notice: 'Address was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @address }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @address.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /addresses/1
  # DELETE /addresses/1.json
  def destroy
    @address.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to addresses_url, notice: 'Address was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_address
      @address = Address.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def address_params
      params[:address]
    end
end
```

Comment: If your routes point `/customers/1/addresses` at the `AddressesController`, nothing in your `CustomersController` is getting called. Which controller is that snippet in? Can you post more of both controllers and your routes file?

Comment: @Kristján i'm sorry but I re-wrote the question for clarity, could you re-read and let me know your thoughts?

Comment: Can you post the full error stacktrace?

Comment: @Pavan it's posted in the question.

Comment: Please post `AddressesController` - is it doing something surprising like inheriting from `CustomersController`?

Comment: @Kristján posted it.

Comment: Something funny's going on - there's no reason your `/addresses` routes should be running `set_customer`. What does `rake routes` show for paths including `/addresses`?

Comment: Weird, error is in customers_controller, you should arriving in addresses_controller. Can you show rake routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access a `/customers/:id` path, `set_customer` can do its job with `params[:id]`, but at `/customers/:customer_id/addresses`, any `:id` is the `Address` ID. I'm not sure why `set_customer` is running at all given the code you've posted so far, but updating it to

```
Customer.find(params[:customer_id] || params[:id])
```

will let it work for both situations.

Answer (score 0):

> How to only run the set_customer on the /customer/:customer_id: route?

`/customers/:customer_id`: How's it possible? You are only gonna get `customer_id` if it is followed by `addresses/:id` like:

```
/customers/:customer_id/addresses/
/customers/:customer_id/addresses/new
/customers/:customer_id/addresses/:id/edit
```

And that actually corresponds the the `show` action in `AddressesController`.

> And exclude set_customer on the /customer/:customer_id:/addresses/ route?

`/customers/:customer_id/:addresses` corresponds to `index` action in `AddressesController`, and there you can exclude `set_customer` for `index` action.